# OpenCV cv2.HoughCircles detection giving bad results on easy picture

Tags: geometry, detection, hough-transform, opencv, python

I am new to opencv and I'm trying to do circle detection using HoughCircles, but it's giving me circles where there are none, and it's not detecting the huge obvious circle that I want it to. I tried changing the parameters but can't get it to work well. What am I doing wrong?

Original Image:
[image: Original Image]

Image After Thresholding:
[image: Image After Thresholding]

Canny Filtered with Circles:
[image]

```python
path=r"minimap.png"
screen = cv2.imread(path,cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
cv2.imshow('Original', screen)

ret,screen = cv2.threshold(screen,200,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
cv2.imshow('Thresholded', screen)

P=50
can = cv2.Canny(screen,P/2,P)
cv2.imshow('Canny', can)

if 1:
    circles = cv2.HoughCircles(screen, cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT, dp=1, minDist=50, param1=P, param2=53, minRadius=0, maxRadius=0)
    print(circles)

    circles = np.uint16(np.around(circles))
    can=cv2.cvtColor(can,cv2.COLOR_GRAY2RGB)
    for i in circles[0,:]:
        # draw the outer circle
        cv2.circle(can, (i[0], i[1]), i[2], (0, 255, 0), 3)
        # draw the center of the circle
        cv2.circle(can, (i[0], i[1]), 2, (0, 0, 255), 5)

cv2.imshow('Circles', can)
cv2.waitKey()
```

Answer (score 0):

You've to play with the `cv2.HoughCircles` parameters and I don't think the same values will give good results for all images. For your image:

```
image = cv2.resize(image, (0,0), fx=0.5, fy=0.5)
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
gray = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (7,7), sigmaX=-1, sigmaY=-1)
circles = cv2.HoughCircles(gray, cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT, 1, rows / 2,
                   param1=130, param2=100,
                   minRadius=0, maxRadius=0)
```

[image: result]

Comment: Thanks for the response! It seems like my thresholding was making things worse. You were right, playing around with the parameters ended up working. I ended up making a GUI so I could adjust the params and see the results in real time. However I'm still having unpredictable results sometimes like this:
https://www.screencast.com/t/fL8QCdeQHpD

The top image shows the Canny filter result being done by the HoughCircles function and it looks like it should be able to see that circle. Do you have any idea what's going wrong in the clip and how I could fix it other than limiting maxradius?

Comment: This is the image from the clip https://www.screencast.com/t/AeZTykBqjz
And the code I used (but it's pretty long): https://pastebin.com/Asej262K

You could see in the clip I was moving the parameters around but it was giving wrong circles. Is that circle just too small for HoughCircles to work on or do you think I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: In both OP code and @zindarod code, minRadius and maxRadius are set to zero, which will return LOTS of results. You may wish to set these parameters.